# Memory Growth Though Overwritten

Tags: python, memory, garbage-collection, python-imaging-library

I have the following Python code. The problem is that the memory usage grows tremendously.
Given that `Image.rotate()` returns a new object, I would have thought that the old object can't have any more references to it and gets deleted.

## Question

What happens, and how can I fix this?

## Code

```
from PIL import Image
src_im = Image.open("input.png")
steps = 120 # Works with 3
angle = 360.0 / steps

rotation = src_im.convert('RGBA')
for _ in xrange(steps):
    rotation = rotation.rotate(angle, expand = 1)

rotation = rotation.crop(rotation.getbbox()).resize(src_im.size)
rotation.save("out.png")
```

This is in Python 2.7.3. Python 3 specific solutions would be acceptable.

Comment: Interesting. I've just tried: gc.collect and explicit del, but none helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not a memory leak, it's the `expand` argument. From the pillow docs (emphasis mine):

> expand – Optional expansion flag. If true, **expands the output image to make it large enough to hold the entire rotated image**.

You can add `print(rotation.size)` size in the loop to see this. Outputs:

```
(852, 646)
(885, 690)
(921, 736)
(959, 784)
(1000, 834)
(1043, 886)
(1089, 940)
(1138, 996)
(1190, 1055)
(1245, 1116)
(1303, 1180)
(1364, 1247)
(1429, 1317)
(1497, 1390)
(1568, 1467)
(1643, 1548)
(1723, 1632)
(1807, 1720)
(1896, 1813)
(1989, 1910)
(2087, 2012)
(2191, 2119)
(2299, 2231)
...
```

To rotate the image without cutting of the borders, use `expand = 1` but then immediately crop to the non-alpha region of the image:

```
for _ in xrange(steps):
    rotation = rotation.rotate(angle, expand = 1)
    rotation = rotation.crop(rotation.getbbox())
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Accepted, and I'll edit in the solution to rotating with out cutting off edges.